# installing mongodb on 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

I was trying to install mongodb into a fairly clean Ubuntu 14.04. I used the following commands:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
```

and the following error occured

```
Setting up mongodb-10gen (2.4.10) ...
chown: invalid user: ‘mongodb:mongodb’
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-10gen (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-10gen
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and I could not find any similar users in /etc/passwd

```
:/var/lib/mongodb$ cat /etc/passwd | grep mongo
mongodb-mms-agent:x:105:111::/nonexistent:/bin/false
```

I don't know how to fix this because mongodb:mongodb simply doesn't exist. I tried to remo

Comment: I think part of the problem is also the lack of documentation on `mongodb-10gen` as the official documentation recommends installing `mongodb-org` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don´t know why your question was downvoted.... 
I never used mongodb or the ubuntu package "mongodb" but it seems that the package description is missing creation of the user - you can create users with "adduser"

http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/adduser

So
    `sudo adduser mongodb`
and reinstalling the package or perhaps
    `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
should help.